# RxJS: Subject does not work after subscribed Observable has ended

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Consider the following code ([on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bhqkh8)):

```ts
const subject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

const second$ = of<number>(3, 4, 5)
  .pipe(delay(100));

subject$.subscribe(console.log);

subject$.next(1);
subject$.next(2);

const subscription$ = second$.subscribe(subject$);

setTimeout(() => subscription$.unsubscribe(), 200);

setTimeout(() => subject$.next(6), 300);
```

I want a Subject, which received data 'manually' (with next), then as long as it exists, subscribes to another observable and afterward can be used as normal.

The above code puts out

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

The `6` is missing, apparently because it is set up after the meanwhile subscribed observable was finished. The same happens if I don't unsubscribe the second observable.

**How is it possible to not finish the Subject after the subscribed Observable was ended?**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `const subscription$ = second$.subscribe(subject$);` is causing your Subject to complete.

The way you pass the Subject to the `subscribe` method it will execute the `subject$.next` when the Observable emits and it will execute `subject$.complete` when the Observable completes. Your Observable completes after emitting 3 items, so the Subject gets completed too. When the Subject gets completed you can't use it to emit new items, which leads us to the fact that you shouldn't complete the Subject.

In order to achieve that, use following:

```
const subscription$ = second$.subscribe((item) => subject$.next(item));
```

This way your Subject won't get completed, when the `second$` gets completed.

Comment: Okay, that's extremely simple. I thought in the direction of a specific pipe or such, but that's easy enough.